# Graphing richtextbox data?

Tags: vb.net, richtextbox, graphing

I'm pretty new to vb so please bear with me here. I have data going into some richtextboxes and I wanted to graph it, what would be the best way of going about graphing something in vb.net like this? I'm thinking rather than trying to read from the textboxes themselves (as the data is being inputted as strings) I'd convert the data going in into doubles and try to graph it. Any suggestions? Would it be possible to graph the data in the actual boxes, since they're strings at that point rather than doubles, or would graphing the numbers just be easier?

Answer (score 1):

I think the whole richtextbox part of your question is just causing confusing. If you have the data out of the textboxes, putting it into a richtextbox and then pulling it back out doesn't make sense.

The values will obviously need to be converted to a number somewhere during the process. Are you using a control to graph, or handling that code yourself? If you're using a control, then check the documentation.

Comment: I was going to handle the code myself, but I'll give using a control a shot thanks!